# Passing props in scene

Tags: react-native, react-native-router-flux

I know react-native-router-flux can pass props via `Actions.key({ text: 'Test' })`. Wonder is it possible to pass the props in the Scene? like something below?

```
<Scene
    key="page1"
    component={Page1Container}
    title="Page 1"
    props={text: 'Test'} //Anything like this in router flux?
/>
```

Comment: are you trying to pass props to `Page1Container` ?

Comment: Yes. I would like to pass props to Page1Container

Answer (score 3):

Instead of passing the reference to `component`, write an inline function component and pass whatever props you want:

```
<Scene
  key="page1"
  title="Page 1"
  component={sceneProps => <Page1Container {...sceneProps} text="Test" />}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can do something like this,

```
<Scene
key="login"
title="Welcome Back"
component={Login}
customProps={yourProps}
/>
```

On Login screen

```
  class Login extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  console.log(this.props.customProps);
  }
```